# what is the role of RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create() in retrofit

Tags: android, rx-java

what is the role of RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create()...

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
.baseUrl("https://api.example.com")
.addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
.build();
```

Comment: Have you tried looking it up in a search engine?
 https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-adapters/rxjava2

Answer (score 6):

From description:

*A call adapter which uses RxJava 2 for creating observables. Adding this class to Retrofit allows you to return an Observable, Flowable, Single, Completable or Maybe from service methods.*

```
interface MyService {
    @GET("user/me")
    Observable<User> getUser()
}
```

Without it you cant describe interface as rx type